# Got error 'GRUB installation failed' while installing ubuntu 12.04 lts on windows 8

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I have Sony vaio with Windows-8. I also want Ubuntu 12.04 as my second OS. I created 50GB root partition and 4GB swap-area partition. But after some time(about 2 minute) while installation I got error:
`GRUB INSTALLATION FAILED : the grub-efi-amd64-signed package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot`
Please help me to solve this issue...

Comment: How did you perform the partitioning of the disk?

Comment: same thing here, did you find a solution yet ?

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but I need Rep! Maybe this will help someone anyway

I followed this guide [UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_UEFI_partition) and I finally got the same error to go away.

If you read 1. **Boot mode matching** -- "If you're **dual-booting with another OS, the two OSes' boot modes should match**. Most computers that ship with **Windows 8 and later use UEFI to boot that OS**, so this configuration dictates use of UEFI mode when installing and booting Ubuntu."

So it seems like you need to download GRUB or get rid of window 8.1. I am not familiar with how to install GRUB, but this link will be useful [GRUB MANUAL](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/gnu/grub/html_chapter/grub_3.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very difficult. However, I would
suggest turning off Secure Boot in the bios then
try again. That is the main cause of installation failure
You might have to set a Supervisor Password in the bios first
before you can turn off secure boot.
Make sure you keep a copy of the password somewhere safe
and where you can easily find it if you need it.
Oh and make certain that if you let ubuntu do a guided install
that it is a UEFI (multi partition) because if it defaults to 
a single partition it will not boot.
I hope this helps you!